# AngularJS SET service variable in controller, and use GET it everywhere else without $watch

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, directive, watch

Here is my basic service to SET and GET the value:

```
.service('companyService', [ function () {
  var self = this
  self.options = {}
  function CompanyService () {
    self.setOptions = function (newObj) {
    self.options = newObj
    }
  }
  return CompanyService()
}])
```

In the global controller I call my $api factory which makes an http request (with promise) to get and set Company Options. I do this only once.

```
.controller('global', ['$scope', '$http', '$api', '$location', '$translate', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$filter', 'toastr', '$window', 'flag', 'companyService', function ($scope, $http, $api, $location, $translate, $rootScope, $timeout, $filter, toastr, $window, flag, companyService) {
$api('GetCompanyOptions', {})
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.companyOptions = response.data
      // doing stuff with the response first
      // ...
      // and setting the value to companyService
      companyService.setOptions($scope.companyOptions)
    })
}])
```

Now almost in every controller and directive I want to use this value. But because the http call takes a while, I had a lot of problems with the timing, so sometimes I was getting empty values with the following: (yes, inside html it automatically uses $apply and variable is not empty, but inside the controller it is)

```
$scope.companyOptions = companyService.options
```

I tried many solutions such as using $watch, $timeout, promises, $rootScope etc. But none worked except using $watch in every controller and directive that I GET the value:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return companyService.options }, function (newVal) {
  // checking if companyService.options is still empty or not
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(newVal)) {
    // Now the options is filled, do some stuff...
  }
})
```

So my questions are:

1. Using $watch in every controller is working. But it is a bit messy so, is there any way to get rid of them?
2. Instead of using $watch in every controller/directive, can I use it once inside the service?
3. Does it make more sense to call the http request inside the service if the 'options' is empty? So that I can use promise? (But I don't prefer this option because of other functions it is better for me to get/set companyOptions inside global controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many solutions I decided the following suits best for me. I hope it may be useful to other people.

I decided to hold Company Options in ngStorage (https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) instead of a service.

So this:

```
companyService.setOptions($scope.companyOptions)
```

Changed to this:

```
$scope.$storage.companyOptions = $scope.companyOptions
```

Then I used a global route resolve with the help of following code, so that this piece of code will work 'before' actual routing occurs. (factory is called checkToken because I also do a http request here to check if user token is valid):

```
  Routes.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  var originalWhen = $routeProvider.when
  $routeProvider.when = function (path, route) {
    route.resolve || (route.resolve = {})
    angular.extend(route.resolve, {
      checkToken: ['$checkToken', function ($checkToken) {
        return $checkToken.checkToken()
      }]
    })
    return originalWhen.call($routeProvider, path, route)
  }
}])
```

And this is the factory itself, where I also watch for the companyOptions to be setted. And route to the page when it is ready:

```
 .factory('$checkToken', ['$q', '$timeout', '$location', '$api', '$rootScope', '$localStorage', function ($q, $timeout, $location, $api, $rootScope, $localStorage) {
  return {
    checkToken: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer()
      $api('IsTokenValid', {})
      .then(function (response) {
          // some unrelated codes here...
          // watching companyoptions in localStorage
          $rootScope.$watch(function () { return $localStorage.companyOptions }, function (newVal) {
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(newVal)) {
              // now that we have companyOptions, resolve and go to page
              deferred.resolve('go to page!')
            }
          }, true)
      })
      return deferred.promise
    }
  }
}])
```

And finally thanks to this solution, in my controllers, this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return companyService.options }, function (newVal) {
  // checking if companyService.options is still empty or not
  if (!$.isEmptyObject(newVal)) {
    // Now the options is filled, do some stuff...
  }
})
```

Became this, and I got rid of the companyService factory:

```
$scope.companyOptions = $scope.$storage.companyOptions
```